# Pyrhon ругается на то, что я написал. не могу понять в чем дело, помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, python-3.x, обработка-ошибок

Написал программу, а питон подчёркивает 'x'

```
 def x:
    x=int(input('Введите код города:'))
    t=int(input('Введите длительность переговоров:'))
    if x=343:
        R=15*t
        print('Такова длительность переговоров в выбранном вами городе',R)
    elif x=381:
        R = 18* t
        print('Такова длительность переговоров в выбранном вами городе', R)
    elif x=473:
        R = 13* t
        print('Такова длительность переговоров в выбранном вами городе', R)
    elif x=485:
        R = 11*t
        print('Такова длительность переговоров в выбранном вами городе', R)
```

И после выводит это:

> def x:
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`def` определяет функцию, а значит надо

```
def x():
```

хотя называть функцию как переменную - первый шаг к огромным ошибкам

затем у вас будет ошибка в

```
if x=343:
```

сравнение в питоне делается через двойное равно - `==`:

```
if x == 343:
```

Comment: исправил '=' на "==", и написал def x(): , однако теперь я ввожу только время, а не саму переменную х, как мне это испраивть?

Comment: я убрал  def x(): всё вышло, спасибо!